# Client script Setting line item on salesorder record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Hi,

I have a custom sublist in SO that includes a simple logic to what items I want to add to the SO.

When I click SAVE on the SO I want to start the logic and to add the items in the custom sublist to the item sublist in SO.

the problem is it's not commit the lines I add, and it's adding always just 1 but not commit it. (I have 5 items to add)

I think the problem is on the 'rate' field. its not setting it at all and that why I cant commit the line.

I am getting the price value but its not set to 'rate', I tried with 'amount' field and still not setting.

```
function saveRecord(context) {

        var currRec = context.currentRecord;

        var count = currRec.getLineCount('recmachcustrecord_top_transaction');

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            var item = currRec.getSublistValue('recmachcustrecord_top_transaction', 'custrecord_cs_contract_details_item', i);
            var startDate = currRec.getSublistValue('recmachcustrecord_top_transaction', 'custrecord_cs_contract_details_start_dat', i);
            var numOfDelvries = currRec.getSublistValue('recmachcustrecord_top_transaction', 'custrecord_cs_contract_details_num_deliv', i);
            var qty = currRec.getSublistValue('recmachcustrecord_top_transaction', 'custrecordcs_contract_details_annual_qua', i);
            var price = currRec.getSublistValue('recmachcustrecord_top_transaction', 'custrecordcs_custrecordcs_unit_price', i);

            for (j = 0; j < numOfDelvries; j++) {
                var sublist = 'item';

                currRec.selectNewLine({
                    sublistId: sublist
                });

                currRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: sublist,
                    fieldId: 'item',
                    value: item
                });

                currRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: sublist,
                    fieldId: 'custcol_top_shipment_date',
                    value: startDate
                });

                var newQty = qty / numOfDelvries;

                currRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: sublist,
                    fieldId: 'quantity',
                    value: newQty
                });

                currRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: sublist,
                    fieldId: 'rate',
                    value: price
                });


                currRec.commitLine({
                    sublistId: sublist,
                })
            }


        }





        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code for commiting the line. I see you have an extra comma there which could cause the issue (code will be expecting another argument)

```js
currRec.commitLine({
    sublistId: 'item'
});
```

Please let me know how this goes!